# Unable to link C shared library in go project

Tags: c, go, shared-libraries, cgo

All I have create a custom package of a C shared library, here
https://github.com/err-him/go-dcc
In this repo I am creating the shared library using Makefile https://github.com/err-him/go-dcc/blob/main/Makefile

When I use this library in this package itself, I am getting successful result but when some other package in GO uses it, it will throw linter error
I am accessing this as

```
  // Package dcc Package provides dcc common code.
  package dcc

   // #cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}/
// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -ldl -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files
// #cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -ldl -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/ -lm -lresolv -ldccmj
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include "dccmj.h"
import "C"      //nolint:depguard,gocritic // Required for calling c library
import "unsafe" //nolint:depguard,gocritic // Required for free the memory

//ChecksumGenerator generates dcc checksum
func ChecksumGenerator(html string) string {
    var checksum string
    input := C.CString(html)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(input))
    ptr := C.CString(checksum)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
    C.fingerprint(input, ptr)
    return C.GoString(ptr)
}
```

and in some other project I am using this as

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    dcc "github.com/err-him/go-dcc"
)

func main() {
    html := "X-Mailin-EID:NTQwMzk0MzB%2BaS5rbGVpbkBob3RtYWlsLmZyfjwyMDIwMDcyMjEzMDcuNjMzMzUwMDQ2MjdAc210cC1yZWxheS5tYWlsaW4uZnI%2BfmVtWlsLmZhbWlsZW8uY29t\nTo: i.klein@hotmail.fr\nDate: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 11:07:08 +0000\nSubject: Confirmation d'inscription\nMessage-Id: <0d7398ec-4e64-4b6e-980d-a44f68c6500d@smtp-relay.sendinblue.com>\nOrigin-messageId: <202007221307.63335004627@smtp-relay.mailin.fr>\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nX-sib-id: g9mCPC8MHeHJarheS6CxOXJ2uYjG4c25hscyFmYoyu14XdNnMaW8cVS8CTXMwg5F4XbZIAmMDg8xsbNkdK2BEOetJi6wPX-NAFp7a3QjOBiy-BGQt5zOAEdMP-MG1PpgYsWVypD322DcHc055aD-o9r_jfW9QIMLvJaNRot3vNs\nX-CSA-Complaints: whitelist-complaints@eco.de\n\r\nBODY starts here, this is test emailYour work Projects Filters Dashboards People Plans Apps Create Search 9+ 3+ Projects Email Sending email-sending (sprint view) 4 days remainingComplete sprint Board Tools 3rd Jan - 14th Jan - 2022 Show tickets assigned to Regular BluSky Only My Issues Recently Updated Insights TO DO 2 IN PROGRESS 3 CODE IN REVIEW 0 QA IN DEV/STAGING 0 DONE IN STAGING 0 QA IN PROD 1 DONE 2 Dharmendra Yadav2 issues Implement DIC pattern - Fetch Process Consumer Implement DIC pattern TaskMajor priority5 Assignee: Dharmendra Yadav ES 33- specs DCC fingerprint DCC fingerprint in email-sending TaskMajor priority1 Assignee: Dharmendra Yadav ES 512- Dharmendra Yadav4 issues expired-process test coverage improve email-sending test coverage improvement TaskMajor priority3 Assignee: Himanshu Gupta ES 321- handle empty emails records in testmail producer/consumer TaskMajor priority2 Assignee: Himanshu Gupta ES 506- POC DCC fingerprint DCC fingerprint in email-sending TaskMajor priority5 Assignee: Himanshu Gupta ES 513- How to do migration GCP migration TaskMajor priority3 Assignee: Himanshu Gupta ES 509- Sagar Sachdev2 issues ES-501Added Kafka consumers for Sendmail Transarchive Project QA for ES-501 Sub-taskMajor priority Assignee: Sagar Sachdev ES 514- Added Kafka consumers for Sendmail Transarchive Project TaskMajor priority3 Assignee: Sagar Sachdev ES 501-"
    checksum := dcc.ChecksumGenerator(html)
    fmt.Println(checksum)
}
```

the error I am getting after go build

> /tmp/go-build3303125424/b408/sendtomta.test: symbol lookup error: /tmp/go-build3303125424/b408/sendtomta.test: undefined symbol: dcc_syslog_init

Can anyone pls help, what I am doing wrong ?
PS: I tried many things but I suspect it's cross platform issue, when I am creating the library I am using macOS but in build I am using ubuntu, any idea ?

Makefile I am using is

```makefile
DESTDIR=./

    STATIC=libdccmj.a

    CC = gcc
    CFLAGS = -I./dccsib/include -Wall -g #-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3
    LDFLAGS = -L. libtool -static -a
    LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=${SRCDIR}/
    LDFLAGS = -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files
    LDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup
    LIBS    = -L. -lpthread -lm -lresolv -ldccmj

    SRC = ./dccsib/dcclib/dccif.c ./dccsib/dcclib/fnm.c ./dccsib/dcclib/get_port.c ./dccsib/dcclib/hstrerror.c ./dccsib/dcclib/inet_ntop.c ./dccsib/dcclib/ipv6_conv.c ./dccsib/dcclib/lock_stubs.c ./dccsib/dcclib/logbad.c ./dccsib/dcclib/mk_su.c ./dccsib/dcclib/msg1.c ./dccsib/dcclib/parse_srvr_nm.c ./dccsib/dcclib/parse_word.c ./dccsib/dcclib/strlcat.c ./dccsib/dcclib/strlcpy.c ./dccsib/dcclib/su2str.c ./dccsib/dcclib/vsyslog.c ./dccsib/dcclib/win32.c ./dccsib/clntlib/aop.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ask.c ./dccsib/clntlib/cdhome.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ck.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ck2str.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ckbody.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ckfuz1.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ckfuz2.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ckmime.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ckparse.c ./dccsib/clntlib/cktbls.c ./dccsib/clntlib/ckwhite.c ./dccsib/clntlib/clnt_init.c ./dccsib/clntlib/clnt_send.c ./dccsib/clntlib/clnt_unthreaded.c ./dccsib/clntlib/daemon.c ./dccsib/clntlib/dnsbl.c ./dccsib/clntlib/escstr.c ./dccsib/clntlib/get_id.c ./dccsib/clntlib/get_secs.c ./dccsib/clntlib/getifaddrs.c ./dccsib/clntlib/hash_divisor.c ./dccsib/clntlib/heap_debug.c ./dccsib/clntlib/helper.c ./dccsib/clntlib/id2str.c ./dccsib/clntlib/inet_pton.c ./dccsib/clntlib/load_ids.c ./dccsib/clntlib/lock_open.c ./dccsib/clntlib/md5.c ./dccsib/clntlib/mkstemp.c ./dccsib/clntlib/msg2.c ./dccsib/clntlib/op2str.c ./dccsib/clntlib/parse_log_opt.c ./dccsib/clntlib/parse_passwd.c ./dccsib/clntlib/parse_whitefile.c ./dccsib/clntlib/print_info.c ./dccsib/clntlib/range.c ./dccsib/clntlib/restart.c ./dccsib/clntlib/select_poll.c ./dccsib/clntlib/sign.c ./dccsib/clntlib/str2cnt.c ./dccsib/clntlib/str2type.c ./dccsib/clntlib/tgts2str.c ./dccsib/clntlib/type2str.c ./dccsib/clntlib/udp_bind.c ./dccsib/clntlib/xhdr.c ./dccmj.c

    OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

    $(STATIC): $(OBJ)
        @echo "[Link (Static)]"
        cd dccsib && ./configure --disable-dccm && cd ..
        ar crv $@ $^

    .c.o:
        @echo [Compile] $<
        @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

    clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ) *~ core tags *.bak Makefile.bak libgeniePi.*

    .PHONY: install
    install: $(STATIC)
        @install -m 0755 $< $(DESTDIR)

    all: install
        $(CC) -g -Wall -o program dccmj.c $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a library shipped by https://www.rhyolite.com/dcc/ and you do not link the shared library exporting that `dcc_syslog_init` symbol to your program or the dynamic library containing that symbol is not found when your binary is loaded and the dynamic linker tries to resolve all the undefined symbols. You can start with running `ldd` on the generated binary to see what libraries are missing.

Comment: I tried to run otool -L libdccmj.a
and output is 

Archive : libdccmj.a
libdccmj.a(dccif.o):
libdccmj.a(fnm.o):
libdccmj.a(get_port.o):
libdccmj.a(hstrerror.o):
libdccmj.a(inet_ntop.o):
libdccmj.a(ipv6_conv.o):

No error or any missing library reported, I have updated the Makefile as well